# Adding image to a radio button list in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to add an image to a radio button list control but its not working..

I tried this..

> RadioButtonList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(String.Format("src='../Colors/Dallas_#625527_1.1.png'>")));

but the whole image tag appears as text

I tried I design time as well

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbListImages" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"><img src="../Colors/Dallas_#625527_1.1.png" alt="" /></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

but it says img tag cant be nested with the listitem tag..  Please help me out..

Comment: this is only html5 validation , just see in browser it should be ok ...

Comment: [Display Images in RadioButtonList Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/display-images-in-radiobuttonlist-control-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: Thanks Vishal.. Silly me..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify the control control, you are trying to set the `src` tag but there is no image control. Try this:-

```
RadioButtonList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("<img src='"+"../Colors/Dallas_#625527_1.1.png"+"'/>"));
```

You can also add this at design time, like this:-

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="imagetest" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Text='<img src="Image1.jpg" alt="img1" />' Value="1" Selected="True" />
         <asp:ListItem Text='<img src="Image2.jpg" alt="img2" />' Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" >
<asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;Images/AddIcon.gif&quot;/&gt; Option1" Value="1">   </asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;Images/1.gif&quot;/&gt; Option2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>

  <asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;Images/2.gif&quot;/&gt; Option3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>

 <asp:ListItem Text="&lt;img src=&quot;Images/3.gif&quot;/&gt; Option4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
```

(OR)
ANother way : 
From Code Behind :  [Display Images in RadioButtonList Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/display-images-in-radiobuttonlist-control-in-Asp-Net/)